# How do I test a model that's not in the models folder with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

I'm using the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem and monkeypatching `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` in an intitializer (`config/initializers/acts_as_taggable_on.rb`). I wrote a spec for my code and put it in `spec/models/tag.rb`, but when I run `rspec spec` or `autotest`, that file is not included in the specs that get run. I also tried putting it in a directory to match the constant hierarchy (`spec/models/acts_as_taggable_on/tag.rb`), but it still didn't run. How do I get RSpec to recognize this spec file? I'm using Rails 3.0.3 and RSpec 2.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your spec-file as `tag_spec.rb`. Rspec expects every spec-file to end in `_spec.rb`. The folder is only relevant to know what your `describe` is about (a model, a controller, ...). In your case i think it doesn't matter, and i would place it in the `spec/lib` instead of the `spec/models` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why is this file in `config`? It belongs in the `lib` directory because it is code of your own that doesn't "fit" into the `app` directory. When you require "spec_helper" in your test this loads the Rails environment which should load all the models and therefore all the files that the models require (this is the important part) and so you'll be able to test it that way.

Comment: I had a typo in my question. The code is in `config/initializers`, not just `config`. I tried putting it in `lib` too. When I had the code in `lib`, the tests relying on the monkeypatch all failed, but pass when it's in `config/initializers`. I verified that `lib` is being added to the autoload path in `config/application.rb`.

Comment: If you re-open a class, then imho the `config/initializers` is indeed the correct place.